# Android Hide Setting Icons in Notification Area

Tags: android, notifications

I need to hide (or change icon) any of this icons this 
http://screencast.com/t/hXilJER86E

Device is rooted. Probably i can use xPosed, but not sure how. Please, if anyone did this, provide proper way.

Thanks